# Slick slider onclick doesn't work when reaching breakpoints

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Currently, I'm having an issue with Slick. The button onlick doesn't work (it's not redirecting the page) when I resize the screen down to where the slideshow crosses another breakpoint. Can you please give me suggestion for this?

Below is my code:

This is my html

```
<div class="cmp-carousel__content slider responsive">
    <button class="cmp-carousel__content-button" >Testing
    </button>
    <button class="cmp-carousel__content-button" >Testing
    </button>
    <button class="cmp-carousel__content-button" >Testing
    </button>
</div>
```

This is my js

```
  $('.responsive').slick({
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow:2,
        slidesToScroll:2,
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1110,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1.5,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: false,
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: true,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 800,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1.3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: false,
                    variableWidth: false,
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: true,

                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 700,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1.2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: false,
                    variableWidth: false,
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: true,

                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. Also see [Ask] for ways to improve your question so that it gets more attention.

Comment: Thank you Ed ! :)